# Create DBContext dynamically asp.net web api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create DBContext dynamically in ASP.NET Web API using EF. : For each new user I will create a specific DB.
My problem is that I would like to create a new DBContext for each new user in my principal BD with existing models.
My question is, is it possible to generate new DBContext for each user ?

Comment: EF will use the configured or given connection string in the DbContext constructor to establish a connection to the database. You can build new connection strings based on the user, which will result in differing databases/instances.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro can you give me an example how to create it ?

Comment: @user3355575: new YourDbContext("yourconnectionstringhere"); You may want to update your constructors in YourDbContext to pass connection string argument down to DbContext.

Comment: in my project we use constructors like public ContextClass(BusinessLogic bl):base(CreateConnectionString(bl)) with appropriate function CreateConnectionString. If your user object is known at context creation time, you can pass it as an argument just as well.

Comment: @user3355575 Are you using dependency injection?